# How to display multiple views in a Django project's template?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project with multiple apps and I would like to manage the template from the project root folder.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {...}
    }]
```

In the homepage `index.html` of the project I'm trying to display `num_exchanges` and `num_accounts` generated in the `views.py` of `app1` and `app2`. The problem is that only `num_exchanges` is printed not the second variable. If I switch the `include` in `urlpatterns` then the second variable is generated not the first one.

How can I print both variables ?

**urls.py** (project)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r"^", include("app1.urls"), name='app1'),
    url(r"^", include("app2.urls"), name='app2'),
]
```

**index.html** (project)

```
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
  <h2>Stats</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Exchanges:</strong> {{ num_exchanges }}</li>
    <li><strong>Account:</strong> {{ num_accounts }}</li>
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py (app1)**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from app1.models import Exchange


def app1_stats(request):
    num_exchanges = Exchange.objects.count()

    context = {
        'num_exchanges': num_exchanges
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

**urls.py (app1)**

```
from django.urls import path
from app1.views import app1_stats


urlpatterns = [
    path('', app1_stats, name='index'),
]
```

**views.py (app2)**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from app2.models import Account


def app2_stats(request):
    num_accounts = Account.objects.count()

    context = {
        'num_accounts': num_accounts
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

**urls.py (app2)**

```
from django.urls import path
from app2.views import app2_stats


urlpatterns = [
    path('', app2_stats, name='index'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to write a new view which loads both variables. Django only supports one view per page load.

This view could call both of the other views. In order for this to work you'll need to replace `render` with [`TemplateResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/template-response/#templateresponse-objects) for both of the stats views.

```py
def combined_stats(request):
    response1 = app1_stats(request)
    response2 = app2_stats(request)
    return render('index.html', {
        **response1.context_data,
        **response2.context_data
    })
```

Personally I would consider getting the context data for `app1_stats` and `app2_stats` in functions outside the view which can be called in `combined_stats`.

```py
def combined_stats(request):
    return render('index.html', {
        **get_app1_stats_context(),
        **get_app2_stats_context()
    })
```

An extreme alternative would be to create a [`context processor`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) for the two apps. This does make the context available (and executes two extra queries) on **every page** on your website.  I wouldn't recommend this, but I guess it is an option if you need to emphatically keep the two apps apart.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your recommendation and replaced  `render` with `TemplateResponse` in `app1_stats` and `app2_stats`, then removed an `include` in `urlpatterns` and finally added `combined_stats` in one of the app but it doesn't work

Comment: @Florent, what error message are you getting?

Comment: There is no error message but one of the view is not displayed

Comment: I inserted `combined_stats` in `app2.views` and removed `url(r"^", include("app1.urls"), name='app1')` from `urls.py`, plus replaced `render` with `TemplateResponse`

Comment: Did you change `path('', app2_stats, name='index')` to `path('', combined_stats, name='index')`?

Comment: No I did not, just did it but now it throws an error `join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'dict'` in `/usr/lib/python3.7/genericpath.py, line 153, in _check_arg_types`

Comment: I have found the issue, the function `combined_stats` should contain `request` as first argument. Please correct your answer and I will accept it. Thanks again!